# Can we keep the code proceeding with try catch block with exceptions

Tags: java, exception

For years I have been printing the stack trace with try catch block, but is there a way we can keep the code running even when an exception occurs. Lets take the following piece of code for example:

```
String [] files= {"a.xml","b.xml","c.xml","d.xml"};

public static void loadAll()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i< files.length;i++)
        {
            File file = new File(files[i]);
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            properties[i] = new Properties();
            properties[i].loadFromXML(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now the above code will exit as soon as a file is not found. I want to continue even if there is an exception, I just want to skip processing of exceptioning iteration. Is it possible.

p.s. I know its a basic question but I never got to learn it.

Comment: Are you really asking HOW to move the try-catch statement somewhere else in your code?  Try it. Move the code.  It's your code.

Comment: @Warren P, if he knew how to use try-catch, he wouldn't be here. Cut him some slack.

Comment: @JeremyKato It is a common issue that new users have a very stiff mental image of Java, and if they're given examples/spoon-fed solutions they never learn (from experience tutoring high schoolers). A tutorial explaining concepts goes a long way, but doesn't mesh as well with Stack Overflow's format.

Comment: @hexafraction, True, it isn't a perfect solution to try to explain Java's workings in a single answer, but many of the users on here at least are willing to take time to briefly throw an explanation out. I guess I feel a bit of sympathy for those who are still learning, though reminding people that google exists at the end of answers gets old quickly

Comment: I don't know how you can reconcile "Stack overflow is a site for professionals" with "Stack overflow is a site for people who can't move line A and B into a different order where B is after A".  So the more slack you cut in the one direction, the more you fill the site up with noise.    We need a site called StackOverflowWithMoreWarmFeelzAndZeroBarriersToEntry.com.   This is not that site. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the try/catch inside the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i< files.length;i++)
{
  try {
    // Do the thing which might throw an exception.
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle it, but don't break.
  }
}
```

---

Note that catching `Exception` is bad, unless the code *actually throws* `Exception`. You should tighten the type of it, e.g. use `IOException`.

You should also use try-with-resources to guarantee that the `FileInputStream` is closed:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file)) {
}
// No need to close explicitly.
```

Or, if you're still in Java 6 or earlier, use `finally`:

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
  // ...
} finally {
  fileInput.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would be helpful.

```
catch(Exception e) {
    if ("Something you expected".equals(e.getMessage()) ) {
         // do what you like to do.
         // program won't crush in this case. 
    } else {
         // for any kind of exception do something common. 
    }
}
```

Or something like this when no file found.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //do something you want to do in this case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to go is making use of `exception handling` mechanisms provided by framework you use. you can separate the exception handling piece of code in a `exception handler`.